# jQuery fadeOut if visible

Tags: jquery

I´ve got an error message, this is shown if a form gets submitted and returns an error.

```
<div id="error"></div>
```

FormCheck.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#error', window.parent.document).html( "There was an Error.");
</script>
```

If there was an error, this message is shown. My problem is: How can i let it fade out after 4 seconds, IF it is visible?

Here´s what i got/researched...

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //if($('#error').is(':visible')) {
    $("#error").ready(function () {
    $("#error").delay(4000)(function () {
$("#error").fadeOut(500);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Couldn´t figure out how to get this done...could anyone be so kind to give me a hint how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do a setTimeout.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#error").is(":visible")) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#error").fadeOut(500);
        }, 4000);
    }
});
```

Also, it looks you are setting the content of the error using Javascript, if so, and you aren't refreshing your page, you can call the `setTimeout` from wherever you are making the error container to `fadeIn`.

Comment: Why not `$("#error").delay(4000).fadeOut(500);`? (The reason `.delay()` didn't work in the OP's code is the incorrect syntax.)

Comment: From the jQuery website: `"The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases."`. Although I think it might work in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, I know what `delay()` does and what `setTimeout()` does. In this case `delay()` will do the job because you won't need to cancel it. (That "between queued ... effects" is a little misleading because `.delay()` can actually be the first "effect" in the queue.)

Comment: +1, i´ll accept this, just saw my other mistake: The #error was displayed from the start...i´ll change my code, so that the div fades in as an error appears...that should do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @nnnnnn `.delay()` uses more than what is needed here, it is a `setTimeout`, but with more involved to it, I guess it is useful for animations and effects if you want to guarantee they occur sequentially and at with clearly defined intervals. In this situation a simple `setTimeout` is enough.

Comment: I'm not saying `setTimeout()` won't work. I'm just saying `$("#error").delay(4000).fadeOut(500);` will achieve the same result while also being easier to read and less to type. Which means it is more "simple" than `setTimeout()`. (And yes, obviously `.delay()` uses `setTimeout()` behind the scenes, but that's an irrelevant implementation detail given that it's not horribly inefficient or anything.)

Comment: I understood that. I know `.delay()` would also work here. I guess I've used `setTimeout` too much last week at work (yes, had to cancel them given certain conditions), so it was the first solution in my head :)

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
 $("#error").ready(function () {
```

should be

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
```

[delay syntax](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeOut(400); //example
```

Comment: doesn´t solve my problem...the fadeOut worked...(if i was fast enough...but it only works once...if i include is:visible it doesnt work at all...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#error").html() != "") {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#error").fadeOut(500);
        }, 4000);
    }
});
```

I'm guessing you really just set text in it. Not it's visibility.

Comment: you saw it, too. it was visible from the start of loading. +1